# Object in memory getting destroyed and redrawn when old object is still drawn

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

So I think my old object is being destroyed from memory so one in every 10 times I open the app it runs drawRect again, but unfortunately the old object is still drawn behind the new one! It doesn't function (only the new object does, but I can still see old one).

```
//Only gets called once
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self initialSetup];

    }
    return self;
}

 //gets called every 10th time or so app is opened and closed but old object is still drawn in background

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Draw for interface builder
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    // bunch of code I took out from here
    UIRectFrame(myFrame);
    CGContextFillRect(context, myFrame);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

How do I get rid of the drawing of my object when drawRect runs a second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawRect:` does not intend to remove an existing similar object from memory automatically.

You would have to keep a reference to the object you created from this `UIView` subclass and once done call below 2 lines before you add a new object and add in view hierarchy:

```
[self.myCustomView removeFromSuperview];
self.myCustomView = nil;
```

Comment: problem is - I create the object in my interface builder - it's an IBDesignable object

Comment: ok, can you show the code where you are re-drawing it. Code that triggers the `drawRect:` again.

Comment: I was creating views within objects - although draw rect is called I cleared the container within it and seems to get rid of the bug. Thanks. Although I'm wondering if there is a better way to potentially do this, as I would really like the old object to just stay forever.